# How do I make changes to my Django HTML view file that extends a base template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django test project that I am working on, and have been working on it for hours now, and I am stuck. I can't add other html syntax into my html file that extends a base template into it.

I have a base template that works on my html view, however, when I make changes inside the html view, it doesn't reflect. Looks like I am missing something between the HTML view, and the base template.

Below is the HTML view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
<!--https://www.anwita-arun.in/ -->
  {% block head %}
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Test Project</title>
    </head>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block  body %}
    <body>
      <h1 style="font-size: 250px"> Testing </h1>
      <p> aloha </p>
      <form method="POST">
        <!-- Form creation with post. No method "post" needed -->
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Insert token -->
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <!-- form variable -->
        <input type="submit">
        <!--  Form input submission -->
      </form>
    </body>
  {% endblock %}
```

Below is the base template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--https://www.anwita-arun.in/ -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.10.1/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/coliff/bootstrap-rfs/bootstrap-rfs.css">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="">
</head>
  {% block head %}
  {% endblock %}

  <body style="scroll-behavior: smooth">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="Header">
        <div class="jumbotron display-5 bg-white p-3 mb-2 text-center">
          <h1 class=" display-5 text-dark mb-5 mt-5" id="header">Augusma J. Photography</h1>
        </div>
        <nav class="text-center navbar navbar-expand-lg text-dark jumbotron navbar-light bg-light"><h2 class="display-3">Creating Memories</h2>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="h2 navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link display-3" style="color:#ff33cc" href="index" target="_blank">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link display-3" style="color:#ff33cc" href="about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link display-3" style="color:#ff33cc" href="contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      </div>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}

    <footer class="text-center text-white" style="background-color: black;">
      <div class="container pt-4">
      <!-- Section: Social media -->
        <section class="mb-4">
          <!-- Facebook -->
          <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg btn btn-outline-primary text-light m-1" href="#!" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-4x"></i></a>
          <!-- Twitter -->
          <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg btn btn-outline-primary text-light m-1" href="#!" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></a>
          <!-- Instagram -->
          <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg btn btn-outline-primary text-light m-1" href="https://instagram.com/augusmajphotography?igshid=5bhelg1i1vwh" target="_blank" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-4x"></i></a>
          <!-- Linkedin -->
          <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating btn-lg btn btn-outline-primary text-light m-1" href="#!" role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-4x"></i></a>
        </div>
      <!-- Grid container -->
      <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="text-center text-light p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
          © 2021 Copyright:
          <a class="text-light" href="https://www.facebook.com/stevenson.gerard">Website Designed by Evolving Technologies</a>
        </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->
      </footer>
      {% block footer %}
      {% endblock %}

  </div>
  <div class="Javascript">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </div>
    {% block JS %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: no. it runs perfectly well with no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work like that, when you extends from base.html, you only have to override the blocks, it should be something like:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />
  {% block head %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  <p>This p tag will always be shown</p>
  {% block content %}
  <p>This content is a placeholder, will be overridden.</p>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

In your inherited template

```
{% extend 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my_extra_custom_css.css" media="screen" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Content from my app, overriding the placeholder.</h1>
{% endblock %}
```